# converting multi war application to spring boot

Tags: web-applications, spring-boot, war

I have a multi war application running on Weblogic, with application.xml and all.
rewriting the web.xml for the first war was easy enough (i pretty much did the same as answered in this question [How to migrate from traditional java web application (with web.xml) to spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240939/how-to-migrate-from-traditional-java-web-application-with-web-xml-to-spring-bo)), but when I moved on to the other wars i realized i want a different classLoader and spring application context for each war.
is there any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: Maybe I don't know what a "multi war" project is. Can't you just create a separate app for each or your wars?

Comment: this is exactly what i'm trying to avoid, I'm trying to preserve the structure i had on Weblogic, and i want my application configuration be as same as possible as it was for on Weblogic (e.g JVM instances, ports etc..).

Comment: I guess you need to spell it out for us then. What is a multi war project?

Comment: Ahh..  application server running more than one war.
meaning there is one JVM, and different wars, each with its own  classLoader and different spring application context etc..
for more see: https://spring.io/blog/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/

Comment: I think you'd better just stick with an app server if you need more than one war running in the same JVM.